# LAN Port as controller

Tags: vb6, lan, interfacing

i need only to get any voltage out from my laptop to control a relay

how to get a signal from a LAN port from any pin ?

in my laptop there is no com Port or lpt Port
also the usb port needs interfacing circuits which is not nessesary
in my simple project

thats why i choosed the LAN Port

i use (visual basic 6)

any help would much appriciated .

Answer (score 0):

While such things as [PoE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_over_Ethernet) exist, normal ports do not provide any power to external devices.  The USB ports are far more likely candidates since they are designed to support powering external devices, though the amount of current supported varies by adapter/hub (most "ports" are actually internal hub ports).

Comment: its must be some form of signals out of LAN ,,, i need to know how to use these signals ,,,thats all .

Comment: You might take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_over_twisted_pair